# Let $R$ be a complete local ring with respect to maximal ideal $I$. Then, intersection of $I^n$ is zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-completions

Let $R$ be a complete local ring with respect to maximal ideal I.

I would like to prove intersection of $I^n$, $n\ge1$ is zero.

My attempt : $R$ is complete with respect to $I$, so $R$ is Hausdorff space.
This is equivalent to $\bigcap_{n\ge1} I^n＝0$.

Is this true? Other proof are welcome.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't it enough to note that if $x$ is a nonzero of the intersection, its image in $R/I\times R/I^2\times\ldots$ should also be nonzero... but it apparently is not nonzero?

Comment: Could you tell me why $R/I×R/I^2・・・$ is zero?

Comment: the product is not zero, I’m saying $(x+I,x+I^2,x+I^3,\ldots)=(0,0,0,\ldots)$ in the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt seems correct but I am not certain if you obtained it without the result to be proven here.

I would just note that if $x\in \cap_j I^j$, then it maps $x$ to $(0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ via the canonical map into the product.  Completeness would imply that the map is injective, so that $x=0$.  One would then conclude the intersection is just $\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry, but why the map is injective? R→R^ is not necessarily injective, indeed, R→R^ is injective if only if ∩I^n＝0. So, composition R→R^→R/I×R/I^2・・・（second → is inclusion）is not always injective.

Comment: @bellow to me, the assumption of completeness means “the canonical map is an isomorphism onto the completion.”  What do you believe “complete” is defined as?

Comment: In this case, I define $R$ is complete with respect to ideal $I$ as $R^＝lim←R/I^n$.

Comment: @bellow that is the definition of *the completion of R*, but what is your definition of *I-adically complete ring R*?

Comment: What do you mean ? That is not just definition of I-adic completion , inverse limit of $R/I←R/I^2←・・・$　'is equal to $R$' is definition of $R$ to be $I$-adically complete here.

Comment: @bellow I think you’re glossing over an important part of the definition of “complete”. The canonical map gives us the image of $R$ inside the limit. To say this image equals the completion implies $R/\cap I^k$ is isomorphic to the completion, rather than $R$.  For $R$ to be complete, that kernel has to be zero, so that $R$ is isomorphic to its completion.

Comment: @bellow  see this for example https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0317

Comment: I'm still confusing, I learned R→R^ is not always injective . According to your reference site, R→R^ is injective.. Where am I missing?

Comment: @bellow non injectivity of the canonical map is one way it can fail to be complete, yes.  That’s why I’m saying complete-> the canonical map is injective.

Comment: What is your definition of canonical map here? A→ A^?

Comment: @bellow $r\mapsto (r+I, r+I^2,r+I^3,\ldots)\subseteq R^\wedge$

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me again why your canonical map $r→（r＋I,r＋I^2,・・・）$ is injective if $R$ is complete?

Comment: @bellow to me, the definition of $R$ being complete means this map is an isomorphism.  Just as the link does.